# Google Proximity Api 403 Unauthorized error

Tags: javascript

When i try to make a POST request to Google Proximity Api i have this error:

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Unauthorized.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

I use a service account to make the request with the Authorization: Bearer + token

Know if Google Proximity Api support the oauth2 service account? Thank you!!

Comment: Have you enabled your project to have access to that particular API? You have to specifically enable every API you want to have access to via the Google Developers Console.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to enable the API for it on your google console project and create credentials using the sha1 of your debug.key. Also if you're using the google oauth playground you have to configure the settings by changing the oauth flow to client side. Next click on use your own oauth credentials and then copy the browser client ID that was created for your oauth from the google console. this should authorize you to do all your work. Source [from google developer](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/how-tos/authorizing)